# how can use i18n values in placeholders or values of inputs in VueJs2?

Tags: vue.js, input, internationalization

Normally, I can replace translated values in codes like this-

```html
<p>{{ $t('greeting') }}</p>
```

but it's not working in vue2 inputs-

```html
<dropdown 
  :items="filteredCityList" 
  ref="city" 
  itemText="persianName"
  :placeholder="{{$t('SearchCityAndHotel')}}" 
  @onSelect="onSelectCity"
>
</dropdown>
```

Even I tried this-

```html
<dropdown 
  :items="filteredCityList" 
  ref="city" 
  itemText="persianName"
  :placeholder="$t('SearchCityAndHotel')" 
  @onSelect="onSelectCity"
>
</dropdown>
```

Comment: This syntax `:placeholder="$t('SearchCityAndHotel')"` should work

Comment: Your 2nd approach seems to work. Can you provide more detail on how this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Your second try should work fine, Here is the working demo. Please do have a look and try to find the root cause of the issue you are facing.

```js
const messages = {
  jp: {
    SearchCityAndHotel: 'XXXXX XXXX XXX XXXXX'
  },
  en: {
    SearchCityAndHotel: 'Search City And Hotel'
  }
}

const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: "en",
  messages
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n@8.15.3/dist/vue-i18n.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" :placeholder="$t('SearchCityAndHotel')"/>
</div>
```